# How can I receive info from a push notification received outside of app that the user did not activate/touch?

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am making an app that will receive push notification alerts depending on which geographical area it is in, in other words not everyone gets the same alert.  I want to have the user be able to store the alerts in the app.  I have the app setup right now to receive the push notifications while in the app and while outside of the app.  If the user touches the notification while outside of the app, I have code in place that will store the info from the push notification sent and store it.  But the way I have it, if the user does not tap on the push notification, that data is lost forever.  How can I get this info so I can store it in an "alerts" section in the app?

So, summary, how can I get info sent in a push notification while outside the app, and the user does not touch the push notification?

Comment: better option is to send request to server on each application launch for alerts data, as their is no guarantee that each time user will receive push notification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the user never acts on a text push notification then the application will never know that the push ever got to the device. 
Also, you should be aware that Apple does not guarantee the delivery of push notification. For example if a user keeps the device offline for a long enough period of time to receive 2 remote push notifications for an app then it will only receive the second one. This is due to to fact that Apple caches only one push, and only keeps the latest one.